# Botón en lugar específico de un div, sin importar tamaño de contenido, con CSS Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Poseo el siguiente código con el cual necesito ayuda con CSS Bootstrap.

Tengo un div el cual posee un botón para realizar funciones en él.
Como pueden ver en el ejemplo corto, el botón esta bien posicionado, en la esquina superior derecha del DIV
¿Cuál es el problema? Que esto no mantiene posición una vez que el contenido es más grande.
En el segundo ejemplo, pueden ver lo que ocurre con claridad.

La idea es que el botón mantenga la posición superior derecha del DIV sin importar el resto.

```css
.showHover {
  visibility: visible;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  right: -12px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: -5px;
}

#divDescription {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

#divDescription:hover {
  border-radius: 1.5rem 0rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55) !important;
}

#divDescription:hover .showHover {
  visibility: visible;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- -->
<div class="pt-3">
  <div id="divDescription" data-toggle="tooltip" title="description" class="d-inline-block text-left shadow" style="max-width: 38rem; border: 1px solid #CCC; padding: .8rem 1.0rem; max-width:100%;">
    Sed ut perspiciatis
    <!-- unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? -->
    <a id="editDescription">
      <i class="fas fa-pen-square showHover" onclick="randomFunction();"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pt-3">
  <div id="divDescription" data-toggle="tooltip" title="description" class="d-inline-block text-left shadow" style="max-width: 38rem; border: 1px solid #CCC; padding: .8rem 1.0rem; max-width:100%;">
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    <a id="editDescription">
      <i class="fas fa-pen-square showHover" onclick="randomFunction();"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hice fue mover el botón al inicio de tu texto:

```html
<div id="divDescription" data-toggle="tooltip" title="description" class="d-inline-block text-left shadow" style="max-width: 38rem; border: 1px solid #CCC; padding: .8rem 1.0rem; max-width:100%;">
   <a id="editDescription">
     <i class="fas fa-pen-square showHover" onclick="randomFunction();"></i>
   </a>
   Sed ut perspiciatis ...
</div>
```

Y al botón le di la siguiente propiedad, con esto ya quedaría:

```css
#editDescription {
  float: right;
}
```

Código final:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.showHover {
  visibility: visible;
  color: black;
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  right: -12px;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: -5px;
}

#divDescription {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

#editDescription {
  float: right;
}

#divDescription:hover {
  border-radius: 1.5rem 0rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55) !important;
}

#divDescription:hover .showHover {
  visibility: visible;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- -->
<body>
  <div class="pt-3">
    <div id="divDescription" data-toggle="tooltip" title="description" class="d-inline-block text-left shadow" style="max-width: 38rem; border: 1px solid #CCC; padding: .8rem 1.0rem; max-width:100%;">
      Sed ut perspiciatis
      <!-- unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur? -->
      <a id="editDescription">
        <i class="fas fa-pen-square showHover" onclick="randomFunction();"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="pt-3">
    <div id="divDescription" data-toggle="tooltip" title="description" class="d-inline-block text-left shadow" style="max-width: 38rem; border: 1px solid #CCC; padding: .8rem 1.0rem; max-width:100%;">
      <a id="editDescription">
        <i class="fas fa-pen-square showHover" onclick="randomFunction();"></i>
      </a>
      Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```